# How to request a package upgrade in the next Ubuntu release

Tags: upgrade, package-management, updates, upstream

I'm looking to move our company from Fedora 13 to the upcoming 12.04.  We've built custom HDF5 1.8.7 RPMs that are newer than the 1.8.4 version in 12.04.  If we go to 12.04 I'd like it to have the latest HDF5 library so I don't need to package it ourselves.  How do I request an upgrade to the package?

I looked at [UbuntuDevelopment](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/) and [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) but I didn't see anything specific.

Would [reporting a bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdf5/+filebug) be appropriate?

Comment: The difference between Ubuntu and other systems like Fedora is that our repositories are not updated as much.  Before something gets updated, it has to undergo testing to determine whether it will break things.  Therefore, the most up to date version of HDF5 may not be available.  Also, 12.04 is currently being developed, and the version available in it may indeed be updated by release.  I'd say wait a while first, before requesting it be upgraded.  Chances are, even then, it might not get upgraded.

Answer (score 10):

File a bug report on Launchpad and tag it with the [`upgrade-software-version`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=upgrade-software-version) tag.

For other tags see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Tags

Answer (score 6):

You will want to review two pages for requesting updates.

First one is the [sync request page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SyncRequestProcess). This page describes the sync process and what is needed to sync a package. Since HDF5 is currently not on the merge list, that might be a good way to go.

Second one - if you want to tackle the merge (there are updates to the package in Ubuntu, btw) is the [merge process page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Merging).

Both of these pages will help with requesting the sync of an updated package and the process for performing the merge since there are changes to the package in Ubuntu that might be relevant to Precise.

Comment: Thanks zoopster.  However, I don't see Debian as having a newer hdf5 than Ubuntu, so is either a sync or a merge appropriate?  Does upgrading hdf5 in this case start in Debian and then merged to Ubuntu, or updated in Ubuntu and then merged to Debian?

Comment: Actually, I found in the experimental branch the version I need:  http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=experimental&keywords=hdf5.  Does Ubuntu pull from experimental?

Comment: Hmm...not sure. I thought it was only unstable, but I could be (and am often) wrong. Putting a request in is the only way to know!

Answer (score 5):

The Ubuntu wiki has (Requesting a new package for Ubuntu): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages

**More links**

FAQ: Requesting new packages / new versions / new features 
( http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?54134-FAQ-Requesting-new-packages-new-versions-new-features )