# How to report that a package is obsolete in ubuntu repositories

Tags: package-management

There are plenty of software that has had newer releases, but has not yet been updated in ubuntu repositories. Is it possible to fill a "bug" report somewhere to tell the maintainer, he should update the package for the next Ubuntu version? An example would be [KBibTex](http://home.gna.org/kbibtex/), where the latest stable version (0.6) has been published nearly a year ago and yet we are stuck with a version 0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the  KBibTex package has been drifting through releases with no version bumps:

- Yakkety (0.4-4): universe/kde
- Xenial (0.4-4): universe/kde
- Wily (0.4-4): universe/kde
- Vivid (0.4-4): universe/kde
- Trusty (0.4-4): universe/kde
- Precise (0.4-1): universe/kde

So well worth filing a bug report which can be done through Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kbibtex/+filebug

Interestingly enough in [the 'Answers' section](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kbibtex/+question/248981) you will see Klabauter mentioning that a new version is available and the answer to this question was: 'I suggest you report a bug.' So in the case of this particular software package I think the way is clear :).

**Further Reading:**

- [AskUbuntu: How to request a package upgrade in the next Ubuntu release](https://askubuntu.com/q/75352/57576)
- [Ubuntu Wiki: Tags for Bug Reports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/Tags)

Comment: Thanks. You can flag this question as duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/75352/how-to-request-a-package-upgrade-in-the-next-ubuntu-release

Comment: I filed the bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kbibtex/+bug/1578960